# Is it possible to get the data of biased and unbiased predicted controlled variables when using APMonitor for Model Predictive Control in Python?

Tags: gekko

I am trying to build a python code for Model Predictive Control using APMonitor. However, I don't want to get the results on an third party online server. Hence, I want to collect the data of the predicted biased and unbiased and plot them on Python myself.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! To increase your chance of getting help, please make sure that you have a [clear question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, working, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You can also solve with option GUI=True to bring up plots in a web-browser. `m.solve(GUI=True)`. This also works in local mode when `m=GEKKO(remote=False)`.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in Python Gekko:

```py
# get additional solution information
import json
with open(m.path+'//results.json') as f:
    results = json.load(f)
```

You can get the unbiased model result by getting the dictionary value of your variable `v` with `v.name`. You can get the biased model prediction with `v.name+'.bcv'`. Here is an example that also shows how to get the raw trajectory information.

[image: Plot raw results]

This gives you access to the raw data. An example shows how to plot from the JSON data.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

m = GEKKO()
m.time = np.linspace(0,20,41)

# Parameters
mass = 500
b = m.Param(value=50)
K = m.Param(value=0.8)

# Manipulated variable
p = m.MV(value=0, lb=0, ub=100)
p.STATUS = 1  # allow optimizer to change
p.DCOST = 0.1 # smooth out gas pedal movement
p.DMAX = 20   # slow down change of gas pedal

# Controlled Variable
v = m.CV(value=0)
v.STATUS = 1  # add the SP to the objective
m.options.CV_TYPE = 2 # squared error
v.SP = 40     # set point
v.TR_INIT = 1 # set point trajectory
v.TAU = 5     # time constant of trajectory

# Process model
m.Equation(mass*v.dt() == -v*b + K*b*p)

m.options.IMODE = 6 # control
m.solve(disp=False,GUI=True)

# get additional solution information
import json
with open(m.path+'//results.json') as f:
    results = json.load(f)

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time,p.value,'b-',label='MV Optimized')
plt.legend()
plt.ylabel('Input')
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(m.time,results['v1.tr'],'k-',label='Reference Trajectory')
plt.plot(m.time,v.value,'r--',label='CV Response')
plt.ylabel('Output')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Comment: You can also name your variables such as x = m.Var(name='x') so that x.name is 'x' instead of 'v1' (default naming scheme on the back-end is v1,v2,v3,etc).